# vapor 3 (beta) ubuntu import CTLS fails

Tags: ubuntu, vapor

import CTLS

failing on Ubuntu

sudo apt install ctls gives "ctls is already the newest version (1.0.1)."

Following environment:
Vapor Toolbox: 3.1.2
Vapor Framework: 2.4.2
Swift version 4.0.3 (swift-4.0.3-RELEASE)
openssl is already the newest version (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.10).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing manually? In the Vapor 3 beta we're using `COpenSSL` now. There shouldn't usually be any need to directly interface with OpenSSL/LibreSSL. Cryptography is part of the `Crypto` module and SSL support by the `OpenSSL`.

Comment: I tried the same code a few days later, and it worked.
Also, following your comment, I removed my import, and it still works.

Thanks for the reply.